# How to display text in html from Django as it is typed in textbox

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to display the text in HTML from Django in proper format.
i.e. Proper space, line break, etc.
I used `<p>{{blog.main_content}}</p>`

This is the screenshot of data added

[image: This is the screenshot of data added]

The text displaying in webpage

[image: The text displaying in webpage]

Please help me to figure it out. How can I display this text in a proper format?

Answer (score 2):

You did not share how it is saved in the database. Assuming it is a plain text save. You can use the `linebreaks` filter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

```
{{blog.main_content|linebreaks}}
```

Comment: Thank you Joao, It worked for me with linebreaksbr  as  `{{blog.main_content|linebreaksbr}}`       just "linebreaks" was not working may be due to my CSS or something. But now the problem is solved thank you.